# Struts validator of field conditional to another variable on the jsp

Tags: validation, jsp, struts2, struts, ognl

I'm using the Struts validator for a JSP validation and I want to know how can I define a field validation depending on the value of another field of my JSP.

I have a list of elements like this one :

```
<s:select name="varName" label="labelVariable" list="listeVariable" listValue="varValue" listKey="varKey"/>
```

And a textfield like this one :

```
<s:textfield name="varNameText" label="labelText"/>
```

In my validator I want to validate the size of the field `varNameText` depending on the selected value on the list.

If my list has the values 1/2/3, I want to validate :

- If `list = 1` the `varNameText` lenght should be 10
- If `list != 1` the `varNameText` lenght should be 12

How can I do this into my xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fieldExpression` validator](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/fieldexpression-validator.html)

> Validates a field using an OGNL expression.

You can find an example of `fieldExpression` validator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23940187/573032).

The point that you can create an expression that using any number of fields populated to action bean before you run the validation against the `valueStack`.

For example

```
<field-validator type="fieldexpression">
  <param name="expression"><![CDATA[varName==1?(varNameText.length()==10):(varNameText.length()==12)]]></param>
  <message>varNameText length should be ${varName==1?10:12}</message>
</field-validator>
```