# Fieldexpression validation Struts 2 with OR AND operator

Tags: java, validation, struts2

```
    </field>
<field name="roleEdit">
    <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="expression">roleEdit == "user" || roleEdit == "admin"</param>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

I want to validate a textfield that allows user just only type `user` or `admin`. If they try to type other words it will show an error message.

Comment: Is the code not behaving as expected?  Can you please edit the question to specify what your expected outcome is and what the current behavior is?

Comment: I just edit my question. Sorry if it makes you misunderstand.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45898983/573032

Answer (score 0):

It is a late answer but you can try using CDATA

```
<field name="roleEdit">
    <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
        <param name="expression"><![CDATA[roleEdit == null || roleEdit.isEmpty() || roleEdit == "user" || roleEdit == "admin"]]></param>
        <message>Only admin and user allowed</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

NB! This wont check if roleEdit is empty or null.